# Bootstrap Clockpicker CSS in web2py

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, web2py

[image: Jquery CSS error]

I am trying to create a widget for input field using jQuery clockpicker plugin. Everything is working but style of the plugin is off. It is supposed to like [this](http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/).

[Link](http://bit.ly/1IabVS1) of current working code.

Is it because of the customized bootstrap CSS that web2py use? If so, how can I overide it without affected current CSS much as I am creating my admin panel of my app around current CSS? Currently I am extending the default 'layout.html' provided by web2py. Also, what is the correct way of using the bootstrap CSS in web2py application.

I am using web2py 2.9.11 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not due to any customizations of Bootstrap but due to the standard Bootstrap 2 CSS rules, which include the following:

```
[class*="span"] {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

The hours and minutes displayed in the clockpicker have the classes "clockpicker-span-hours" and "clockpicker-span-minutes", respectively, both of which contain the string "span" and therefore trigger the `float: left` rule shown above. Presumably the clockpicker is designed for Bootstrap 3, which does not include the above rule.

You'll either have to upgrade your site to Bootstrap 3, change the above rule in your current Bootstrap 2 CSS (which may have other consequences), or modify the markup or CSS of the clockpicker.

Comment: Thank you! for your answer. If I upgrade my website to bootstrap 3, will the styling of the current default forms and other item will change or remain same because when I tried to update the design of current forms and menu got lost. Is there any way to upgrade to bootstrap 3 without facing such issues.

Comment: You might want to try [this scaffolding app](https://groups.google.com/group/web2py/attach/b39b336517ec2eca/web2py.app.welcome3.w2p?part=0.1&authuser=0), which is based on Bootstrap 3. Regarding form styling, you can set the "formstyle" argument to "bootstrap3_stacked" or "bootstrap3_inline", or create your own formstyle function.

Comment: Thank you, again. Your answer and comment were very informative. I came across one of your [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/9ipT2xkXMhc/BzTyNTKcE4QJ) at web2py-group that has cleared all my doubts about use of Bootstrap in web2py.